# access shared data in swift file from objective c file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am new learning swift and objective c, I am facing a problem and hope any one can hep me

I have the following swift file

```
class DataManager {

    var splash : SplashResponse
    var categories : CategoriesResponse
    var banners : BannersResponse

    static let instance = DataManager()

    init () {

        splash = SplashResponse.init();
        categories = CategoriesResponse.init();
        banners = BannersResponse.init();
    }
}
```

it is a singlton class to allow me to store some data in application memory, I want to access this data in a method exist in another objective c file

How can I do that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this is an amazing guide for seeing Objective-C/Swift code in the opposite language (you might have to scroll down): https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/5700898

Comment: I have tried it, but I can't access the data inside the shared class